# Passing variables to a viewScript Decorator

Tags: zend-framework, arguments, zend-form, partial, zend-decorators

I have tried adding a partial to my form using the Zend Form's viewScript decorator, however i seem unable to pass along variables to the partial. Here's my code:

In the controller i add the form:

```
$form = new Content_Form_ContentForm(array("categories" => $sortedCategories));
$form->submit_button->setLabel("Add content");
$this->view->form = $form;
```

Then inside the form i add the viewscript:

```
public function setCategories($categories) {
    $this->setDecorators(array(array('ViewScript', array(
            'viewScript' => 'partials/dtreePartial.phtml',
            'List'=>"{$categories}",
    ))));
}
```

I have tried printing the options for the view script by using `print_r($this->getDecorator('ViewScript')->getOptions());` wich results in `Array ( [viewScript] => partials/dtreePartial.phtml [List] => Array )`
However when i run it all, the script returns an error about the List not existing.

I have the feeling i am missing something but i am unsure as to what it is. Any advice or solutions will be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
'List'=>"{$categories}",
```

Because you put the variable inside quotes, it gets cast to a string.  In PHP, when you cast an array to a string, the result is always the word `Array`.

Simply change to:

```
'List'=> $categories,
```

and it should work as you expect.

Comment: I think i need to buy glasses :) Thanks for the assist